# Cell stays coloured and doesn't go back to transparant

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone help me? When I type BOB or DAB the cell gets a red colour, but when I delete text BOB, the cell stays red.

Hope someone is willing to help because I just can't find the problem...

*I Removed a part of the code because it was to long..

```
Private Sub newSub(RolesList As String, FirstCellAddress As String, Target As Range)
    
    Dim dRng As Range
    Dim aRng As Range
    Dim Curr() As String
    Dim cMatch As Variant
    Dim n As Long
    Dim isFound As Boolean
    
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
        If Not IsError(cel) Then
            Curr = Split(cel.Value, Delimiter)
            For n = 0 To UBound(Curr)
                cMatch = Application.Match(Curr(n), Roles, 0)
                If IsError(cMatch) Then
                    isFound = True
                    Exit For
                Else
                    ' Remove this block if you don't need case-sensitivity.
                    If StrComp(Curr(n), Roles(cMatch - 1), _
                            vbBinaryCompare) <> 0 Then
                        isFound = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next n
            If isFound Then
                isFound = False
                If dRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set dRng = cel
                Else
                    Set dRng = Union(dRng, cel)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next cel
    
    rng.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If Not dRng Is Nothing Then
        dRng.Interior.Color = xlNone
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: That would be one of the many reasons to use the built-in Conditional Formatting over using VBA to hard code colors based on conditions.

Comment: Ty for this particular problem I might try that.